# Graph is displaying the out of plot area in Core Plot and not visible on iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am Using Core Plot in my iPhone application. My X axis Contains Date (i.e., may be hours , one week, and one month.) And my Y axis contains Weather information. When user selects the particulate place Y range changes. Using the Automatic label format. I am taking my plot ranges as below

```
NSDecimalNumber *max1= [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:max];
NSDecimalNumber *min1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:min];
NSDecimalNumber *length = [max1 decimalNumberBySubtracting:min1];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((oneUnit*7.0f))];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[min1 decimalValue] 
                                                length:[length decimalValue]];
```

But the problem, for places the graph plotting out of the plot area and not visible, how can I adjust the plot values?

Comment: Do you want to adjust the plot data or the plot space ranges?

Comment: I want to adjust the plot space ranges

Comment: In Y PlotSpace range some values are missing , i.e, for Example Min =0.215870 and Max = 0.216020, now it is showing Y-Range as o.21588 to 0.21601

Comment: That might be a rounding error with the floats. Does it still happen if you store min and max as doubles? Try logging `min1` and `max1` to make sure you didn't lose any digits in the conversion.